# Implementing dynamic user interfaces ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, dynamic, user-interface

I would appreciate any assistance with techniques/ strategies to implement the scenario below:
1. SQL Database has a Customer table with some fields.
2. User is allowed to add additional custom fields and specify the data type and some rules such as value is required etc. 
3. When the user loads the user interface, these custom fields need to appear as any other standard field with validation on the field. 
4. When the user saves the changes, the values in these custom fields need to be saved to the database

Technology 
We are still in the design phase - so open to all suggestions. But skillset is mainly in SQL, ASP.Net webforms

Question 
1. What is the best way to achieve item 2 above - a separate table that stores TableName, FieldName, DataType, Rules etc? Any feedback would be appreciated.

2. What is the best way to achieve items 3 and 4 above - I have been reading up on Dynamic Data, Data Annotations etc. All look promising, but I am unsure about the full extent to which these can be utilized to solve our problem.

Once again, appreciate any assistance in helping us come up with a good design.

Answer (score 0):

In my most recent application I did it like so:

1. A database table called `CustomFields` with this schema: `(CustomFieldId int PK, DisplayName nvarchar(50), Class int, Type int)`
2. Each extensible entity has a new column called `CustomFieldValues` which is `nvarchar(MAX)`. Each entity has a number that goes in the `Class` of CustomFields. The CustomFieldValues
3. And then some ASP.NET MVC view-hackery to display custom fields.

Basically, the table `CustomFields` defines each field (its name, data-type, and the class of entity it's associated with), and each entity's `CustomFieldValues` property lists the actual data, it is serialized as a CSV string which contains only simple values: strings, ints, decimals, etc, no complex-types or graphs.

I used ASP.NET MVC for the front-end stuff because WebForms is actually harder to work with, especially with dynamically-added fields. I did have to make some changes with binding to ensure my Model was picked-up, but everything's good.

If you're using MVC, you'll need a custom ViewModel class that looks like this:

```
public class CustomFormViewModel {

    public List<CustomFieldViewModel> CustomFields { get; set; }

}

public class CustomFieldViewModel {

    public Int32 CustomFieldId { get; set; } // the field ID for definition lookup
    public String Value { get; set; }
}
```

Then in the view:

```
<% for(int i=0;i<Model.CustomFields.Count;i++) { %>
    <%= Html.TextBoxFor( m => m[i].Value ) %>
<% } %>
```

In your action, everything should be magically bound for you:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CustomForm(CustomFormViewModel model) {
    model.CutomFields[0].Value == "foo";
}
```

Simples!

Note that ASP.NET MVC does have some bugs here-and-there with binding this, have fun finding them!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick response. I will keep this in mind as we start the design!